# Подскажите как сделать чтобы код срабатывал если тегов с текстом больше чем один.

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Скрипт обрезает текст в зависимости от указаного количества символов. Сейчас работает коректно только если на странице один параграф с текстом, если больше то в остальных отображает такое же количество текста как в первом.

Отбирает теги по атрибуту data-text-over

```
<p data-text-over="52">
        Луций Марций Филипп (лат. Lucius Marcius Philippus; около 136 — после 76 гг. до н. э.) — древнеримский политический деятель и оратор из плебейского рода Марциев, консул 91 года до н. э., цензор 86 года до н. э. Луций Марций считался одним из лучших ораторов эпохи. В гражданских войнах 80-х годов до н. э. Луций Марций сначала был на стороне марианской партии, но когда Луций Корнелий Сулла во второй раз двинулся на Рим, Филипп перешёл на его сторону. В последующие годы Луций Марций был самым влиятельным членом сената.
</p>


$(document).ready(function(){
var elemText = $('*[data-text-over]');  
var text = elemText.text(); 
var textMaxLength = elemText.attr('data-text-over'); 
var textWithSpace = text.replace(/^\s+/, ""); 
var arrWithSpace = textWithSpace.split("");  
elemText.text("");

if(arrWithSpace.length > textMaxLength){
var newText = arrWithSpace.slice(0, textMaxLength); 
for(var i=0; i < textMaxLength; i++){
    elemText.append(newText[i]);
}   
elemText.append('...'); 
}
else{
  elemText.text(text);
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('[data-text-over]').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text().replace(/^\s+/, '')
        , maxLength = $(this).data('text-over');
      if (maxLength < text.length) {
        text = text.substring(0, maxLength) + '...';
      }
      $(this).text(text);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<p data-text-over="52">
    Луций Марций Филипп (лат. Lucius Marcius Philippus; около 136 — после 76 гг. до н. э.) — древнеримский политический деятель и оратор из плебейского рода Марциев, консул 91 года до н. э., цензор 86 года до н. э. Луций Марций считался одним из лучших ораторов эпохи. В гражданских войнах 80-х годов до н. э. Луций Марций сначала был на стороне марианской партии, но когда Луций Корнелий Сулла во второй раз двинулся на Рим, Филипп перешёл на его сторону. В последующие годы Луций Марций был самым влиятельным членом сената.
</p>

<p data-text-over="25">
    Луций Марций Филипп (лат. Lucius Marcius Philippus; около 136 — после 76 гг. до н. э.) — древнеримский политический деятель и оратор из плебейского рода Марциев, консул 91 года до н. э., цензор 86 года до н. э. Луций Марций считался одним из лучших ораторов эпохи. В гражданских войнах 80-х годов до н. э. Луций Марций сначала был на стороне марианской партии, но когда Луций Корнелий Сулла во второй раз двинулся на Рим, Филипп перешёл на его сторону. В последующие годы Луций Марций был самым влиятельным членом сената.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так, однако я бы советовал оптимизировать скрипт и минимизировать запросы к DOM - `$(this).append(newText[i])` в цикле это далеко не лучшее решение.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-text-over]').each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text(); 
        var textMaxLength = parseInt($(this).attr('data-text-over')) || 52; 
        var textWithSpace = text.replace(/^\s+/, ""); 
        var arrWithSpace = textWithSpace.split("");  
        $(this).text("");

        if(arrWithSpace.length > textMaxLength){
          var newText = arrWithSpace.slice(0, textMaxLength); 
          for(var i=0; i < textMaxLength; i++){
              $(this).append(newText[i]);
          }   
          $(this).append('...'); 
        }
        else{
          $(this).text(text);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p data-text-over="52">
        Луций Марций Филипп (лат. Lucius Marcius Philippus; около 136 — после 76 гг. до н. э.) — древнеримский политический деятель и оратор из плебейского рода Марциев, консул 91 года до н. э., цензор 86 года до н. э. Луций Марций считался одним из лучших ораторов эпохи. В гражданских войнах 80-х годов до н. э. Луций Марций сначала был на стороне марианской партии, но когда Луций Корнелий Сулла во второй раз двинулся на Рим, Филипп перешёл на его сторону. В последующие годы Луций Марций был самым влиятельным членом сената.
</p>
<p data-text-over="10">
        Луций Марций Филипп (лат. Lucius Marcius Philippus; около 136 — после 76 гг. до н. э.) — древнеримский политический деятель и оратор из плебейского рода Марциев, консул 91 года до н. э., цензор 86 года до н. э. Луций Марций считался одним из лучших ораторов эпохи. В гражданских войнах 80-х годов до н. э. Луций Марций сначала был на стороне марианской партии, но когда Луций Корнелий Сулла во второй раз двинулся на Рим, Филипп перешёл на его сторону. В последующие годы Луций Марций был самым влиятельным членом сената.
</p>

<p data-text-over="30">
        Луций Марций Филипп (лат. Lucius Marcius Philippus; около 136 — после 76 гг. до н. э.) — древнеримский политический деятель и оратор из плебейского рода Марциев, консул 91 года до н. э., цензор 86 года до н. э. Луций Марций считался одним из лучших ораторов эпохи. В гражданских войнах 80-х годов до н. э. Луций Марций сначала был на стороне марианской партии, но когда Луций Корнелий Сулла во второй раз двинулся на Рим, Филипп перешёл на его сторону. В последующие годы Луций Марций был самым влиятельным членом сената.
</p>
```